# Regex starts with 79 and have length of 9

Tags: java, regex

Hello everyone, 
               I m new to regex and trying to apply two specific regexes in java.

1 - Regex starts with 79, contain only numbers and length must be 9. My solution is

```
 ^(79)\\d{9}$
```

But not matching this string. 791234567.

2 - Another regex is start with 79 or 78, contain only numbers and length must be 10.
My solution is `^(79-78)\\d{10}$`

Both are different and need different regex for each case. Any help would be great.

Comment: `79` is already 2 digits. Use `\d{7}` instead of `\d{9}`.

Comment: ...and no need for the capture group. But depending on how you're using the regex, you may need start and end anchors. Also, alternatives aren't written `79-78`, they're written `79|78` (and you will want a group around it if you're combining it with something else, but probably a non-capturing group).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using a look ahead assertion

```
^(?=79)\d{9}$
^(?=79|78)\d{10}$
```

otherwise matching first two character then 7 or 8 remaining

```
^79\d{7}$
^7[89]\d{8}$
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mdBTOM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the regex:
`^79\\d{7}$` and `^7(8|9)\\d{8}$`

Now for the explanation:

- "79" has two characters in it, therefore `79\\d{9}` would match 11 characters
- `(79-78)` is not what you thought it would be, it is actually just capturing the characters "79-78" in this specific order, what you want is alternation : `(79|78)`
- 78 and 79 have the "7" in common, so `(79|78)` can become `7(9|8)`
- "79" still has 2 characters in it, therefore you'd need to match only 8 digits afterward

Answer (score 0):

```
\\d{9}
```

means (another) 9 digits.
You need 7 (9 - 2 you already used)

same for the 2nd question,
use this instead

```
\\d{8}
```

to indicate 8 additional numbers

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does not work because you did not account for the 2 characters that `79` occupies.

It should be

```
^79\d{7}$
```

This means "starting with 79, with 7 more digits following it". All together there are exactly 9 characters.

Your second regex does not work because `-` does not mean "or". `|` means "or".

```
^(79|78)\d{8}$
```

Again, it should be `\d{8}` instead of `\d{10}` for the same reason.